# Extract first value from a JSON dictionary in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-value

I have various translations stored in a JSON dictionary. I extract the values with JSON_VALUE (for that example I use a variable instead of a column. In real life it is a nvarchar(max) table column):

```
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(200) = '{"en":"green","de":"grün","fr":"vert"}'
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."fr"') -- returns 'vert'
```

Now I am implementing a fallback mechanism for the case the user's culture does not exist in the dictionary. I want to try different cultures, with a coaloesce:

1. user culture (fr-fr)
2. two-letter user culture (fr)
3. english (en)
4. as a last option I want to return just *any* translation in that dictionary (FirstOrDefault).

Fallback of tree different (known) cultures is easy (Options 1-3):

```
SELECT COALESCE(JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."fr-fr"'), JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."fr"'), JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."en"')) -- returns 'vert'
```

My question: Is there a way to extract just any (the first) key-value pair of a JSON dictionary and then return the value of it (Option 4)? For example if there is only a german (de) translation and the user culture is french (fr), they should still get the german translation. Better than nothing.

I tried accessing it with '$[0]' but that obviously did not work.

Access with OPENJSON does work indeed, but I guess there will be a loss in performance with that. I need it for sorting tables alphabetically.

Comment: can you show example data and expected data?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi  there is sample data, see the first code block, and the expected *behaviour* is well explained.

Comment: There is no syntax for retrieving "any" property from a JSON object with `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_QUERY`. If performance is a concern arguably none of this processing should be done in SQL Server anyway, but in any case you should test rather than guessing -- `SELECT TOP(1) [value] FROM OPENJSON(...)` should scale just fine because the JSON is parsed incrementally (which you can verify by adding some unparsable rubbish at the end and seeing it won't cause an error).

Comment: Maybe you could look into properly normalized design, where each language / translation is a single row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to generate rows from json .

You can specify the order of the generated rows using the conditional order `ORDER BY CASE` then get the first one using `TOP(1)` :

```
SELECT TOP(1) [key] , [value] 
FROM OpenJson(@json)
ORDER BY case when [key] = 'fr-fr' then 1
              when [key] = 'fr' then 2
              when [key] = 'en' then 3
              else 4 end;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vMQRqj5i)

Comment: Turns out this is the only solution for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote, because even though I am using SO since 10 years, I still don't have enough reputation points

Comment: Reputation is earned from contributions, not length of membership, @keen4000 . YOu might have been a member for almost 10 years, but you've not contributed anything in those 10 years, so you've not earned any reputation.